# Perform a frequency distribution count on a generator, and return values that are greater than n

Tags: python-3.x, list, count, generator, frequency

Is there a way to perform a count on a generator object that is pointing to a list of lists? If so, can I make the count operation output a generator object (of counted items) of previous generator object? I then would like to get a frequency count.  I am using generators to conserve memory and prevent crashes. My real data set/list is enormous!

I have a generator object, 'gen_list', created from a list of lists, I'll just show you what the list looks like if the generator object was printed:

```
In [1]: ll = [(('color'), ('blue')), (('food'), ('grapes')), (('color'), ('blue'))]

# create generator object 'test2'
In [2]: genobj = (each for each in ll)

# create a generator object with counted items
In [3]: count = (test2.count((i), i) for i in test2)

# list count
In [4]: list(count)
```

This creates the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-83b1c94e3edd> in <module>()
----> 1 list(count)

<ipython-input-70-829ea68a1314> in <genexpr>(.0)
----> 1 count = (test2.count((i), i) for i in test2)

AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'count'
```

So I am stuck here. If I can resolve this, I can move onto getting a frequency count (in the form of a generator object) which would look something like: 
[(2, ('color', 'blue')), (1, ('food', 'grapes')), (2, ('color', 'blue'))]
Then I would only want save items with values greater than 2, for visual analysis.

Comment: Would a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) work for your data?  `collections.Counter(ll)` would give you `Counter({('color', 'blue'): 2, ('food', 'grapes'): 1})`

Comment: Yes, I have considered that, but  how can I, for example, set that up in a list comprehension, so it only returns values greater than two? Remember that I mentioned I was trying to create iterable (generator) objects to avoid bringing in new datasets into memory because my computer will crash.

Comment: How big is the actual data you're trying to count?  `Counter` works best when there are many repeated items, and will perform poorly if there are very few repeated items.  `(k for k, v in Counter(ll).items() if v > 2)` would be a generator of items greater than 2

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, I think that might be what I am looking for. I'm not very comfortable with  dictionaries yet. My dataset is huge. I am focusing on one column where each cell has about a hundred sentences. I then join a group of cells (possibly thousands) into one corpus. Then the corpus is broken up into sentence tokens (which are also lemmatized) and paired with their original sentence, yielding tokens-sentence pairs. I then compare each pair against each other for similarity and any tokens-sentence pair that repeats is removed because it is considered boilerplate information.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh. So your code does create a generator object: a = (k for k, v in Counter(genobj).items() if v > 2), but print(list(a)) outputs empty brackets: []. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the `test1` that you use to generate `genobj`?

Comment: Crap, sorry, that was supposed to be 'll'.

Comment: Did you already exhaust your `genobj` before sending it to `Counter`?  There's really no reason for the explicit generator there, iterating over a list will create a list iterator.

Comment: No, not exhausted. Can't figure it out. I turn the list into a generator object (genobj) because in my actual code, the counter uses a generator object - not a list. If I slip up anywhere and let an actual iterable be created, my computer crashes because the data set is so large.

Comment: For your example `ll`, there is no item with a count greater than 2.  `(k for k, v in Counter(ll).items() if v > 2)` is those items with counts greater than *or equal to* 2.

Comment: Wow I feel dumb, meant to use '>=2'. Will chalk this up to lack of sleep. Sorry to waste your time. Feel free to post your code as answer and I'll confirm. Thanks.